# Magento per customer discount based on qty

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I need to apply a discount to certain products based on a per customer discount table but part of this is that there are quantity price breaks for each item in the table on a per customer basis.

What observer is best to hook into in order to apply this discount when the item is added to the cart AND if the qty in the cart is later updated?

Comment: you are still looking for your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set your code when item added to cart, you can used this observer

```
<events>
    <checkout_cart_save_before> 
       <observers>
         <checkout_cart_save_before_handler> 
            <type>model</type> 
            <class>Vendor_Extension_Model_Observer</class> 
            <method>AddToCartBefore</method>  
         </checkout_cart_save_before_handler>
       </observers>
    </checkout_cart_save_before>
</events>
```

If any item update from cart, you can used this event.

```
<events>
  <checkout_cart_update_items_before>
    <observers>
      <checkout_cart_update_items_before_handler> 
        <class>Vendor_Extension_Model_Observer</class> 
        <method>UpdateCartBefore</method>  
      </checkout_cart_update_items_before_handler>
    </observers>
  </checkout_cart_update_items_before>
</events>
```

Comment: I'll be giving this a try today. Thanks

Comment: I am already used this. One you try just put query if you have.

Answer (score 0):

What I actually ended up using was...

```
        <sales_quote_add_item>
            <observers>
                <fluidaccess>
                    <class>Magnesium_Access_Model_Observer_Product</class>
                    <method>setCartQtyProductDiscount</method>
                </fluidaccess>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_add_item>

        <checkout_cart_update_items_before>
            <observers>
                <fluidaccess>
                    <class>Magnesium_Access_Model_Observer_Product</class>
                    <method>setCartQtyUpdateProductDiscount</method>
                </fluidaccess>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_update_items_before>
```

I used sales_quote_add_item rather than checkout_cart_save_before because I am updating prices on the fly and cart_save_before just wasn't working the way I wanted it to.